# XCode Swift: Signal SIGABRT error by create an own UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have inserted a CollectionView in my XCode App which I now want to initialize in the cellForItemAt indexPath by my own UICollectionViewCell class and then also display it. But when I try to start my app it crashes and I get this error as can be seen in the screenshot. For the first time I thought that I had forgotten to register the new cell, but I also get an error during the registration process (see the screenshot two). I hope someone can help me. Best regards

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has the cell a nib? Did you register the cell? Copy/paste code, not only screenshot...

Comment: It would help to see the setup of the CollectionView. Missing the cell registration is a possible reason of the error you are seeing.

Comment: Have you read the error message? It’s obviously related to Autolayout.

Comment: What is `testCell`? It should be the name of the class that defines your cell. Not the instance. So either you are providing a wrong thing, or your class name is wrong, and should be `TestCell`

Comment: Hey. thanks for your answer! Where do you see `TestCell`? Do you mean the reuse indentifier? Ich have register my own cell with         `testCollectionView.register(TestCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "testCell")` but that doesn´t work to.